# An implementation of Levenshtein Distance algorithm in modern C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, edit-distance

Below is an implementation of [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

I am trying to use modern C++ features as much as I can, i.e. auto, no pointer / raw memory but I feel like it is a constant struggle.

Code:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace utils
{
    auto getLevenshteinDistance(std::string_view string_1, std::string_view string_2)
    {
        const auto size_1{ string_1.size() };
        const auto size_2{ string_2.size() };

        if (size_1 == 0) return size_2;
        if (size_2 == 0) return size_1;

        std::vector<std::size_t> costs(size_2);
        for (std::size_t k{ 0 }; k <= size_2; ++k) costs[k] = k;

        std::size_t i{ 0 };
        for (const auto& itr_1 : string_1)
        {
            ++i;
            costs[0] = i + 1;
            auto corner{ i };

            std::size_t j{ 0 };
            for (const auto& itr_2 : string_2)
            {
                ++j;
                auto upper{ costs[j + 1] };

                if (itr_1 == itr_2)
                {
                    costs[j + 1] = corner;
                }
                else
                {
                    auto t{ upper < corner ? upper : corner };
                    costs[j + 1] = (costs[j] < t ? costs[j] : t) + 1;
                }

                corner = upper;
            }
        }

        return costs[size_2];
    }
}
```

For instance, I can't use `auto` when declaring my vector, because there is no `std::make_vector` (like `make_tuple` for instance).

Also I'm developing anxiety for implicit conversions; for instance I could have written

```
auto i{ 0 };
```

instead of

```
std::size_t i{ 0 };
```

But given that the value will be put into an array containing type `std::size_t`, I'd rather just have it be of the right type immediately. Lots of stuff like that is bothering me.

Even looping through the array by `const auto&` seems weird when I'm still having a count variable.. Doesn't advantage disappear, and I might as well just `for (int i = 0; ..)`

Any suggestions for improvements in the way of modern, good practice, and performance is appreciated.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Are you somehow obsessed with the “almost always auto” style? I mean, auto is handy when you want the type to be deduced, but I don’t think you need to change `std::size_t i = 0;` to `auto i = std::size_t{0};`.

Comment: You're accessing out of bounds for several of your array references: `costs[k] = k;`, `costs[j + 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Invalid access

There are several occurrences of out-of-range access as [1201ProgramAlarm's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238641/an-implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-algorithm-in-modern-c#comment468015_238641) pointed out:

> ```
> for (std::size_t k{ 0 }; k <= size_2; ++k) costs[k] = k;
> ```
>
> ```
> costs[j + 1]
> ```
>
> ```
> return costs[size_2];
> ```

This problem can be fixed by increasing the size of `costs` by one.

## Usage of the standard library

> ```
> std::vector<std::size_t> costs(size_2);
> for (std::size_t k{ 0 }; k <= size_2; ++k) costs[k] = k;
> ```

Use `std::iota`:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> costs(size_2 + 1);
std::iota(costs.begin(), costs.end(), std::size_t{0}); // or 0_zu; see below
```

> ```
> auto t{ upper < corner ? upper : corner };
> costs[j + 1] = (costs[j] < t ? costs[j] : t) + 1;
> ```

Use `std::min`:

```
costs[j + 1] = std::min({upper, corner, costs[j]}) + 1;
```

## `auto`

When you want the type of a variable to be deduced, `auto` is handy, because you don't have to write the type or expression twice.  When you want the type of a variable to be fixed, however, `auto` becomes cumbersome — so feel free to write

```
std::size_t i = 0;
```

An alternative is to use a user-defined literal: (there's a proposal [P0330 Literal Suffix for (signed) `size_t`](https://wg21.link/p0330) to add builtin literals for `std::size_t`)

```
namespace util_literals {
    constexpr std::size_t operator""_zu(unsigned long long number)
    {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(number);
    }
}
```

So you can write:

```
using namespace util_literals;
auto i = 0_zu;
```

Also, instead of

> ```
> for (const auto& itr_1 : string_1)
> ```

it is more common to access characters by value.  Also, `itr` is a misleading name for characters:

```
for (char c_1 : string_1)
```

## Simplification

This check is redundant:

> ```
> if (size_1 == 0) return size_2;
> if (size_2 == 0) return size_1;
> ```

because the algorithm works well with empty strings.

---

Here's my version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

std::size_t Levenshtein_distance(std::string_view string_a, std::string_view string_b)
{
    const auto size_a = string_a.size();
    const auto size_b = string_b.size();

    std::vector<std::size_t> distances(size_b + 1);
    std::iota(distances.begin(), distances.end(), std::size_t{0});

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size_a; ++i) {
        std::size_t previous_distance = 0;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < size_b; ++j) {
            distances[j + 1] = std::min({
                std::exchange(previous_distance, distances[j + 1]) + (string_a[i] == string_b[j] ? 0 : 1),
                distances[j] + 1,
                distances[j + 1] + 1
            });
        }
    }
    return distances[size_b];
}

int main()
{
    std::string string_a;
    std::string string_b;
    while (std::cin >> std::quoted(string_a) >> std::quoted(string_b)) {
        std::cout << Levenshtein_distance(string_a, string_b) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Input:

```
kitten sitting
corporate cooperation
123 ""
"" ""
```

Output:

```
3
5
0
0
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0ZValXTB8RPkFAYS))